# using enum in a enum class

Tags: python

The following code, for "MAX_SPEC = 51 + OFFSET" complains that "Expect type 'int', got 'AP' intead", but the value of MAX_SPEC is correctly calculated.

```
class AP(Enum):                  
    OFFSET = 6
    MAX_SPEC = 51 + OFFSET 
    AP_MAX = MAX_SPEC + 18
```

but when I change it to the following code, pycharm is ok. But when I run it, I got

"MAX_SPEC = 51 + OFFSET.value

AttributeError: 'int' object has no attribute 'value'"

```
class AP(Enum):                  
    OFFSET = 6
    MAX_SPEC = 51 + OFFSET.value 
    AP_MAX = MAX_SPEC.value + 18
```

How Can let pycharm not complain but still get correct value when I run it?

Here is a test program:

```
from enum import Enum


class AP(Enum):
    OFFSET = 6
    MAX_SPEC = 51 + OFFSET.value
    AP_MAX = MAX_SPEC.value + 18


if __name__ == "__main__":
    ap = AP
    print(ap.MAX_SPEC.value)
```

Comment: You can simply ignore the pycharm error. However the question is: why is that an enum to begin with? The purpose of enum is to have a text label for some numeric constant. But all those values (except for OFFSET) are calculated, they are not constants.

Comment: use `pycharm` tag if the issue is specific to it.

Comment: @freakish: "Constant" isn't "literal", though. It's perfectly reasonable to define a constant as the value of some expression.

Comment: These variables are related, and I want put them together. So OFFSET is defined and used by other enums. I just ignored these pycharm error. Thanks for these comments.